# MVC5 Async ActionResult. Is that possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, cqrs

In our application we have CQRS: we have `IAsyncCommand` with `IAsyncCommandHandler<IAsyncCommand>`.

Usually the command is processed via Mediator like this:

```
var mediator = //get mediator injected into MVC controller via constructor
var asyncCommand = // construct AsyncCommand
// mediator runs ICommandValidator and that returns a list of errors if any
var errors = await mediator.ProcessCommand(asyncCommand);
```

That works fine. Now I noticed that I do a lot of repetitive code in controller actions:

```
public async virtual Task<ActionResult> DoStuff(DoStuffAsyncCommand command)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(command);
    }

    var result = await mediator.ProcessCommandAsync(command);

    if (!result.IsSuccess())
    {
        AddErrorsToModelState(result);
        return View(command);
    }
    return RedirectToAction(MVC.HomePage.Index());
}
```

And this patterns repeats over and over in many-many controllers. So for single-threaded commands I've done simplification:

```
public class ProcessCommandResult<T> : ActionResult where T : ICommand
{
    private readonly T command;
    private readonly ActionResult failure;
    private readonly ActionResult success;
    private readonly IMediator mediator;


    public ProcessCommandResult(T command, ActionResult failure, ActionResult success)
    {
        this.command = command;
        this.success = success;
        this.failure = failure;

        mediator = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMediator>();
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            failure.ExecuteResult(context);
            return;
        }

        var handlingResult = mediator.ProcessCommand(command);

        if (handlingResult.ConainsErrors())
        {
            AddErrorsToModelState(handlingResult);
            failure.ExecuteResult(context);
        }

        success.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
    // plumbing code
}
```

And after some plumbing done, my controller action looks like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult Create(DoStuffCommand command)
{
    return ProcessCommand(command, View(command), RedirectToAction(MVC.HomePage.Index()));
}
```

This works well for sync-commands where I don't need to do `async-await` patterns. As soon as I try to do `async` operations, this does not compile, as there is no `AsyncActionResult` in MVC (or there is and I can't find it) and I can't make MVC framework use async operations on `void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)`.

So, any ideas how I can make a generic implementation of the controller action I quoted on top of the question?

Comment: I don't see where anything named `AsyncActionResult` gets involved. Just return a Task<ActionResult> or Task<T> if you implement a generic method. Asynchronous actions always return tasks. `async void` is a very specific syntax  used only used for asynchronous event handlers (or handler like methods) and *nowhere* else. The asynchronous equivalent of a `void` method is a function returning `Task`. The equivalent of a function is a function returning a `Task<TResult>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, I'm quite aware that I should not use `async void`. And I can't just return Task<ActionResult> because I need to check if `ModelState` is in valid state before I execute mediator, and that involves going through MVC pipeline and pulling `ModelState` out of the framework somehow.

Comment: It seems like you are mixing up different concerns, like the incoming request with the action itself *and* the expected result. At this point your ProcessCommandResult class looks like a Controller. If you want to override validation, binding etc there are other mechanisms in MVC. In fact, what you have here violates CQRS - you are using the response (ActionResult) as if it were the command itself by implementing ICommand.

Comment: To put it another way - an ActionResult is a DTO whose only purpose in this world is to be serialized in an HTTP response body.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I am totally violating the SRP. But this is the best way so far I managed to reduce duplicating code and hide the validation nastiness. And it smells. Hence the question. I'm happy to go away from implementation of ActionResult, but can't come up with a better way.

Comment: CQRS is a higher level concept than MVC. You can implement it eg by using one container for commands and another for queries/reports. It has nothing to do with how the container itself is implemented. I suggest you rethink the architecture of your application. Right now, you are trying to convert the result of a Command (that's what an action is ) to the command itself

Comment: I think you are confusing CQRS with CQS. Command Query Responsibility Segregation is a deadlock avoidance technique, while Command Query Separation is a general principal used for reducing complexity by separating idempotent queries from mutating commands. CQRS is based on CQS, but CQRS is something you only need when multiple actors are acting on a single resource)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems overly complex, highly smelly (contains both service location, and other smells) and seems to miss the point of what ActionResults are (command objects themselves, really).

In reality, this is a good example of [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/134199).  Rather than asking about your actual problem, which is refactoring common code in your action methods in an async friendly way, you have instead come up with an overly complex solution that you think solves your problem.  Unfortunately, you can't figure out how to make it work, so you ask about THAT problem rather than your real problem.

You can achieve what you want with a simple helper function.  Something like this:

```
public async virtual Task<ActionResult> DoStuff(DoStuffAsyncCommand command)
{
    return await ControllerHelper.Helper(command, ModelState, _mediator,
         RedirectToAction(MVC.HomePage.Index()), View(command), View(command));
}

public static class ControllerHelper
{
    // You may need to constrain this to where T : class, didn't test it
    public static async Task<ActionResult> Helper<T>(T command,
        ModelStateDictionary ModelState, IMediator mediator, ActionResult returnAction, 
        ActionResult successAction, ActionResult failureAction)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return failureResult;
        }

        var result = await mediator.ProcessCommandAsync(command);

        if (!result.IsSuccess())
        {
            ModelState.AddErrorsToModelState(result);
            return successResult;
        }

        return returnAction;
    }

    public static void AddErrorsToModelState(this ModelStateDictionary ModelState, ...)
    {
        // add your errors to the ModelState
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make it a stateful object and inject the mediator through cascaded dependencies via constructor injection.  It's not easy to inject ModelState, unfortunately, so that still needs to be passed as a parameter to the method.

You could also just pass the string for the ActionResults, but since there's no RedirectToActionResult object to new up, you'd have to mess with initializing a RedirectToRoute object and it's just easier to pass the ActionResult.  It's also much easier to use the Controllers View() function than to construct a new ViewResult yourself.

You could also use the `Func<ActionResult>` approach that Sambo uses, which makes it lazy evaluate, so it only calls the RedirectToAction method when necessary.  I don't think RedirectToAction has enough overhead to make it worth it.

Comment: That's almost identical to what I ended up with myself after enough of iterations of refactoring.

Comment: @trailmax - yeah, I didn't notice the question was a few months old.. it got bumped by Sambo.  Glad you came to the same conclusion... I dislike base controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an Action is still the best place to handle your logic instead of using an ActionResult.

If the code is duplicated, why not use a base class with a protected helper method...?

```
public class BaseCommandController : Controller
{
    protected IMediator Mediator { get { return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof (IMediator)) as IMediator; } }

    public async virtual Task<ActionResult> BaseDoStuff<TCommand>(TCommand command, Func<ActionResult> success, Func<ActionResult> failure)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return failure();
        }

        var result = await Mediator.ProcessCommand(command);

        if (!result.IsSuccess())
        {
            AddErrorsToModelState(result);
            return failure();
        }

        return success();
    }

    private void AddErrorsToModelState(IResponse result)
    {
    }

}
```

Your controller's actions are then rendered as...

```
public class DefaultController : BaseCommandController
{
    protected async virtual Task<ActionResult> DoStuff(DoStuffAsyncCommand command)
    {
        return await BaseDoStuff(command, () => RedirectToAction("Index"), () => View(command));
    }
}
```

Comment: We had exactly that and it does not work for us for various reasons.